# Change order of modules in Doxygen without INPUT tag

Tags: module, doxygen

I have three .dox files which define groups, as follows

ModuleA.dox

```
/*! \defgroup Module_A Module A 
*/
```

ModuleB.dox

```
/*! \defgroup Module_B Module B 
\ingroup Module_A 
*/
```

ModuleC.dox

```
/*! \defgroup Module_C Module C 
\ingroup Module_A 
*/
```

Generating the documentation, the modules are listed as follows

```
>ModuleA 
        ModuleB 
        ModuleC
```

However, I want to change the order and want ModuleC to appear BEFORE ModuleB

I am aware that this can be done by specifying the order in which the .dox files are read by Doxygen, i.e.

```
@INPUT  = ModuleA.dox ModuleC.dox ModuleB.dox
```

Unfortunately, I do not have access to the doxygen file to do this. The whole directory in which the above .dox files are contained is read and then processed by doxygen, using some makefiles which I am not allowed to tamper with.

Is there any other way to change the order of the modules "ModuleB" and "ModuleC" ?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this was as follows:

@INPUT  = ModuleA.dox ModuleC.dox ModuleB.dox